# Extract Json php MultilineString coordinates from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, polyline, multilinestring

How do I insert and extract the following from a MySQL database using php. I have tried 'Multiploygon, Multilinestring, GeometryCollection' but cannot get the correct output as below.

1) JSON file to insert

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "GID": 4728339, "PRCL_KEY": "0000T0JT005300000056000010", "PRCL_TYPE": "E", "LSTATUS": "R", "WSTATUS": "C", "GEOM_AREA": 1558.723715, "COMMENTS": "", "TAG_X": 30.920674, "TAG_Y": -25.452585, "TAG_VALUE": "1\/56", "TAG_SIZE": 0.000020, "TAG_ANGLE": 6.282645, "TAG_JUST": "MC", "ID": "T0JT00530000005600001", "DATE_STAMP": "2010\/10\/05" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 30.920838, -25.452746 ], [ 30.920876, -25.452431 ], [ 30.920876, -25.452431 ], [ 30.921498, -25.452367 ], [ 30.921498, -25.452367 ], [ 30.921492, -25.452341 ], [ 30.921492, -25.452341 ], [ 30.920476, -25.452445 ], [ 30.920476, -25.452445 ], [ 30.920441, -25.452719 ], [ 30.920441, -25.452719 ], [ 30.920838, -25.452746 ], [ 30.920838, -25.452746 ] ] ] } }
,
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "GID": 4822420, "PRCL_KEY": "0000T0JU004000004445000000", "PRCL_TYPE": "E", "LSTATUS": "R", "WSTATUS": "C", "GEOM_AREA": 391.799538, "COMMENTS": "", "TAG_X": 31.337096, "TAG_Y": -25.508292, "TAG_VALUE": "4445", "TAG_SIZE": 0.000020, "TAG_ANGLE": 0.002299, "TAG_JUST": "MC", "ID": "T0JU00400000444500000", "DATE_STAMP": "2013\/05\/22" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 31.336972, -25.508217 ], [ 31.337103, -25.508419 ], [ 31.337103, -25.508419 ], [ 31.337234, -25.508350 ], [ 31.337234, -25.508350 ], [ 31.337101, -25.508149 ], [ 31.337101, -25.508149 ], [ 31.336972, -25.508217 ], [ 31.336972, -25.508217 ] ] ] } }
```

2) Output needed

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"properties":{"name":"T0IS00210000007100000"},"type":"Polyline","coordinates":[29.245262,-26.95622,29.245272,-26.956412,29.245272,-26.956412,29.245282,-26.956603,29.245282,-26.956603,29.245826,-26.956581,29.245826,-26.956581,29.246128,-26.956398,29.246128,-26.956398]}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"properties":{"name":"T0IS00210000007300000"},"type":"Polyline","coordinates":[29.245211,-26.955206,29.245231,-26.955589,29.245231,-26.955589,29.246086,-26.955554,29.246086,-26.955554,29.246066,-26.95517,29.246066,-26.95517,29.245211,-26.955206,29.245211,-26.955206]}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"properties":{"name":"T0IS00210000007500000"},"type":"Polyline","coordinates":[29.245171,-26.954439,29.245191,-26.954822,29.245191,-26.954822,29.246047,-26.954787,29.246047,-26.954787,29.246037,-26.954594,29.246037,-26.954594,29.245558,-26.954614,29.245558,-26.954614]}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"properties":{"name":"T0IS00210000010200000"},"type":"Polyline","coordinates":[29.2436,-26.954444,29.243605,-26.95454,29.243605,-26.95454,29.243623,-26.954887,29.243623,-26.954887,29.244051,-26.95487,29.244051,-26.95487,29.244028,-26.954427,29.244028,-26.954427]}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"properties":{"name":"T0IS00210000030400000"},"type":"Polyline","coordinates":[29.242942,-26.949925,29.242963,-26.950314,29.242963,-26.950314,29.243388,-26.950298,29.243388,-26.950298,29.243374,-26.950036,29.243374,-26.950036,29.243367,-26.949915,29.243367,-26.949915]}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"properties":{"name":"T0IS00210000010400001"},"type":"Polyline","coordinates":[29.243429,-26.951122,29.243439,-26.951314,29.243439,-26.951314,29.243867,-26.951296,29.243867,-26.951296,29.243857,-26.951105,29.243857,-26.951105,29.243477,-26.95112,29.243477,-26.95112]}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"properties":{"name":"T0IS00210000010500000"},"type":"Polyline","coordinates":[29.243288,-26.956694,29.243309,-26.957098,29.243309,-26.957098,29.243328,-26.95746,29.243328,-26.95746,29.243755,-26.957443,29.243755,-26.957443,29.243716,-26.956676,29.243716,-26.956676]}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"properties":{"name":"T0IS00210000010600000"},"type":"Polyline","coordinates":[29.243261,-26.956168,29.243288,-26.956694,29.243288,-26.956694,29.243716,-26.956676,29.243716,-26.956676,29.243697,-26.956312,29.243697,-26.956312,29.243688,-26.956151,29.243688,-26.956151]}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"properties":{"name":"T0IS00210000010800000"},"type":"Polyline","coordinates":[29.243178,-26.954558,29.243195,-26.954905,29.243195,-26.954905,29.243304,-26.954901,29.243304,-26.954901,29.243623,-26.954887,29.243623,-26.954887,29.243605,-26.95454,29.243605,-26.95454]}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"properties":{"name":"T0IS00210000009400000"},"type":"Polyline","coordinates":[29.244647,-26.952287,29.244653,-26.952395,29.244653,-26.952395,29.244682,-26.952394,29.244682,-26.952394,29.244697,-26.952669,29.244697,-26.952669,29.245078,-26.952654,29.245078,-26.952654]}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"properties":{"name":"T0IS00210000009500000"},"type":"Polyline","coordinates":[29.244599,-26.95165,29.244609,-26.951846,29.244609,-26.951846,29.244652,-26.951844,29.244652,-26.951844,29.244661,-26.952032,29.244661,-26.952032,29.244825,-26.952025,29.244825,-26.952025]}},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"properties":{"name":"T0IS00210000009800000"},"type":"Polyline","coordinates":[29.244753,-26.950491,29.244773,-26.950875,29.244773,-26.950875,29.244987,-26.950866,29.244987,-26.950866,29.244967,-26.950483,29.244967,-26.950483,29.244753,-26.950491,29.244753,-26.950491]}}
```

3) Current PHP code

```
$geojson = array( 'type' => 'FeatureCollection', 'features' => array() );

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbquery)) {
    $feature = array(
        'type' => 'Feature', 
      'geometry' => array(
      'properties' => array(
            'name' => $row['LINK_ID']),

        'type' => 'Polyline', 
        'coordinates' => array((float)$row['lon1'],(float)$row['lat1'],(float)$row['lon2'],(float)$row['lat2'],(float)$row['lon3'],(float)$row['lat3'],(float)$row['lon4'],(float)$row['lat4'],(float)$row['lon5'],(float)$row['lat5'],(float)$row['lon6'],(float)$row['lat6'],(float)$row['lon7'],(float)$row['lat7'],(float)$row['lon8'],(float)$row['lat8'],(float)$row['lon9'],(float)$row['lat9'])
            )

        );
   // array_push($geojson, $feature);
   array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, MySQL does not have a native ST_AsGeoJSON function like PostGIS. Fortunately, you can use geoPHP in combination with a little script I wrote to achieve the same result.

1. Export your GeoJSON file to a MySQL spatial table using OGRor QGIS.
2. Download [geoPHP](https://github.com/phayes/geoPHP) and my [MySQL to GeoJSON](https://github.com/bmcbride/PHP-Database-GeoJSON/blob/master/mysql_geojson.php) script.
3. Fill in the proper db connection settings and this script should output your MySQL spatial table in proper GeoJSON format.